# jq with date and variable issue

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

The below is running in bash as a script that is invoked manually at the moment.

I have been banging my head on this for the past few hours. I cannot seem for the life of me to pass a variable into jq no matter what way I do to it. When I set the variable manually without referencing my jq command and echo it, it works. However when it is placed inside my command it does not work.

I am thinking it has something to do with either the `fromdateiso8601` or the `<` operator is causing an issue.

`timestamp.json` contains a few hundred of the below in the file. I need to reference every single one and pull out any that older than 45 days. Here is what I have tried.

```
date -d -45days +%s >> 45days.text
days=$(<45days.text)
echo $days    
cat $_fileformated | jq 'select(.Timestamp | . == null or fromdateiso8601? < "$days" ) .serverrname' >> $filereport
cat $_fileformated | jq -r --arg days "$days" 'select(.Timestamp | . == null or fromdateiso8601? < "$days" ) .serverrname' >> $filereport
cat $_fileformated | jq -r --arg days "$days" 'select(.Timestamp | . == null or fromdateiso8601? < env.days ) .serverrname' >> $filereport
cat $_fileformated | days="$days" jq 'select(.Timestamp | . == null or fromdateiso8601? < 'env.days' ) .serverrname' >> $filereport    
{
    "servername": "xxxxxxxx",
    "Timestamp": "2018-06-12T13:41:08Z"
}
```

Comment: Please give a sample input (is that the last four lines) and the desired output.

Comment: Double quotes inside single quotes will not be resolved. So `'something "$days" something'` will not replace `$days`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sample input and days=1524953907, the following query:

```
jq --argjson days $days '
  select(.Timestamp | select(fromdateiso8601 > $days)).servername'
```

yields:

```
"xxxxxxxx"
```

One can use `--arg days $days` but then you'd have to convert the string to a number, e.g. by `$days|tonumber`

Comment: You are my hero, that worked. I was reading up on argjson thinking it might be better but I couldn't figure out the double (fromdateiso8601?) part. Thank you!